# Can I run Export-SPWeb from another machine using PS Remoting?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run SharePoint Export/Import from a remote machine. I can get it to work if I remote on to the individual box, but want to run it from another machine.

I’ve enabled PSRemoting on each box, but I’m getting command not recognised errors.
So, when I run:

```
Invoke-Command –ScriptBlock {Export-SPWeb –Identity $SourceIdentity –Path $Path –ItemURL $ItemUrl} –ComputerName $SourceComputer
```

I get:

> The term Export-SPWeb is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program. ......

I’ve tried running:

```
Invoke-Command –ScriptBlock {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell} –ComputerName $SourceComputer
```

beforehand but it makes no difference.

Is what I’m doing possible, and if so, what am I not doing?

Answer (score 2):

How about saving your script to a `ps1` file and then run it as an expression.

So, content of `Example.ps1`:

```
$path ="YOUR PATH"
$ItemUrl = "YOUR ITEM URL"
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Export-SPWeb –Identity $SourceIdentity –Path $Path –ItemURL $ItemUrl
```

And then run it:

```
$Path = "C:\PATHTOExample.ps1" 
Invoke-Expression "$Path"
```

Comment: That gives me the same problem as if I were running from another machine. It says it cannot find an SPWeb object with that ID or URL. I assume, because its looking on the local box, not the remote machine I'm attempting to execute against.

Comment: Even if you add the ComputerName parameter to it?

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem.

```
Invoke-Command –ScriptBlock {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell; Export-SPWeb –Identity $SourceIdentity –Path $Path –ItemURL $ItemUrl;} –ComputerName $SourceComputer
```

You have to add SharePoint PSSnapin just before you execute the command since it `Invoke-Command` creates new runspace for the remote machine.